# Where are the Greasemonkey scripts kept in Portable Firefox?

Tags: firefox, portable, greasemonkey

I'm trying to transfer settings between my old copy of Portable Firefox and the latest version of it.

Where can I find the Greasemonkey scripts that I downloaded before so I can copy them over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's at `<Firefox-Portable-folder>\Data\profile\gm_scripts`

Answer (score 0):

Where user is the username you use to login to your computer.

In XP:
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default\gm_scripts

In Vista:
c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default\gm_scripts

Select the profile you want to use (if you only have one, it should look something like xxxxxxxx.default). Finally select the gm_scripts folder.

On a MAC:
On a Mac, you can find your profile at ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles.

Comment: um, wouldn't that then defeat the point of having a portable version?

Comment: (Yes, I'm just looking for the settings for the portable version actually.)